# Append/Prepend items to a ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm using a `ListView` to populate a list of items, followed by a button:

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
    budgetEntry(snapshot.data[0]),
    budgetEntry(snapshot.data[1]),
    budgetEntry(snapshot.data[2]),
    FlatButton(
      child: Text('Manage budgets'),
      onPressed: () { },
    )
  ); // ListView
```

[image]

This works, but I want to know how I can achieve the same result with a dynamic number of items (`snapshot.data.length`) instead of manually using `snapshot.data[0]`, `snapshot.data[1]`, ...

I've tried using `ListView.builder` like so, but now I can't append a button at the end of the ListView:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return budgetEntry(snapshot.data[index]);
  });
```

Comment: `itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1` and inside `itemBuilder` check if `index == snapshot.data.length` and return either budgetEntry or button

Comment: @pskink thanks for the idea, it's novel but seems somewhat hacky. Is that the official way™ of doing things?

Comment: hacky? it is a normal thing: if you have N items in the list and one additional item (button at the bottom) then `itemCount` should be set to N + 1